# Playframework: Is persistance of form values is possible?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I am curious to know how can we persist values of form while reloading the page in Play framework. For example, I have a drop down with List of countries. On selection of Drop down only, user can move forward to selection in another drop down which allows user to select parameters of that country. Here is the code

```
<td onchange="countryselected()">
                <select name="ddlCountries">
                                @for(countries <- countrylist) {
                            <option value="@countries.countryId"
                            @if(countries.countryId == Integer.parseInt(selected)) {
                            selected="selected"
                            }
                            >
                            @countries.countryDesc</option>
                        }
                        </select>
        </td>
```

The `"countryselected()"` function has

```
  document.getElementById("postButton").click();
```

which creates a artificial click, But when I  come back to the page I have the List of countries also modified to default.

For example, If I select a country I go back to code get the filled form and again send the filled form  along with the list of countries to the SCALA page. Hence the countries drop down selection is lost and it is again ordered in the same way. Any good way of tackling this.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your onchange event an ajax call and respond with some json to update your page using javascript